# How to reset PageCache by tag? How to tag PageCache?

Tags: caching, yii2

I'm using type PageCache with some sql dependency in my controller. I need to reset cache in with controller by one click. How can I tag with?

```php
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\filters\PageCache',
                'only' => ['category','index','tags','tag', 'post'],
                'duration' => Yii::$app->params['blog_section'],
                'variations' => [
                    Yii::$app->request->get('code'),
                    \Yii::$app->request->get('page'),

                ],
                'dependency' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
                    'sql' => 'SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM post',
                ],

            ],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TagDependency`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-tagdependency) combined with `DbDependency` by [`ChainedDependency`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-chaineddependency#$dependOnAll-detail):

```
'dependency' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\ChainedDependency',
    'dependencies' => [
        new \yii\caching\DbDependency([
            'sql' => 'SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM post',
        ]),
        new \yii\caching\TagDependency([
            'tags' => 'posts',
        ]),
    ],
],
```

Cache will be revalidated when either `SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM post` result will change or `TagDependency` with name `posts` will change. You can revalidate tag by:

```
TagDependency::invalidate(Yii::$app->cache, 'posts');
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but I have error "Call to a member function evaluateDependency() on array"

Comment: If I have dynamic data (cart, favorite) in the header, I cant use PageCache type caching? because the page is cached with header and footer... Which of types cache I must using? Example, if I have a blog

Comment: You can use `renderDynamic()` to handle dynamic content inside of cached content: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-fragment#dynamic-content